# Geometry Nodes - How to mirror geometry along normal

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to mirror geometry along Z normal of Reflection Plane?
(When Local coordinates of geometry nodes modifier similar to global)

Like on the picture, but with geo nodes

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is a node setup which mirrors: (sorry, but just mirrors)

[image]

i found this answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector

and so i called my variables n and d

result:

[image]

by changing n you influence the mirroring (or the angle of the mirror)