# isolating part of a mesh after boolean in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I've created a node tree that is able to separate a cube according to its planar symetries as in the image below [image: Split cube]

Now I would like to access geometry of one of the tetrahedron to perform some modifications that I will further mirror on all the other tetrahedron.
Anyone could help me on how to access one tetrahedron ?

Comment: You are probably better off doing the reverse workflow of creating a stand-alone tetrahedron with the desired shape then instancing it to form the cube, if you wish to propagate changes.

Comment: This approach is definitely worth a try. I found this topic for the symmetries : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251877/geometry-nodes-how-to-mirror-geometry-along-normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the *Separate Geometry* node in combination with the *Mesh Island* node, to access separate parts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I will conduct both methods (yours and the one proposed by  @Duarte Farrajota Ramos) to see what works best in my case