# Extract only GreasePencil lines

Tags: compositing-nodes, grease-pencil, lineart, light-groups

I want to extract only the lines used in LineArt, is there a way to do this?
I tried setting the object path to GPencil, but it doesn't seem to be masked correctly.
The line will also be composited with other outputs ( LightGroup ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [Thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/231014/168324) has a lot of relative value of what you're looking for.

For your case, you should move all the objects into a Holdout collection and make the background transparent. To activate Holdout, within the `Outliner`, select the `Filter` drop down menu and within the `Restriction Toggles` select the `Holdout` icon for your collection. To make the background transparent as well, go to `Render Properties` $\rightarrow$ `Film` $\rightarrow$ and select `Transparent`.

[image]

When you render your line art with the empty background, it should be usable in a `Render Layers` node within the compositor.